# Vertex Weight Proximity with an empty is not rendering

Tags: vertex-weights

I subdivided a plane and applied distortion modifier and distorted the mesh permanently. Then with corrective smooth and vertex weight modifier with target an empty i tried to change the mesh. The mesh change is happening in rendered view but when render the animation for output its not happening, just a still image. The animation is still there as in the screenshots.
Any solution?

Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: Highest value of the vertex weight proximity is most likely too high compared to the size of the mesh.

Comment: I tried by changing it, but not rendering